# Unable to convert list into string in python

Tags: python

How do i convert a list into a string in python?

I have tried using a `for` loop but i want a simpler method to join.

Input:

```
['I', 'want', 4, 'apples', 'and', 18, 'bananas']
```

Output:

```
I want 4 apples and 18 bananas
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best method, but since you don't want to use a `for` loop:

```py
>>> ("{} " * len(my_list)).format(*my_list).strip()
'I want 4 apples and 18 bananas'
```

Answer (score 0):

`" ".join([str(x) for x in ['I', 'want', 4, 'apples', 'and', 18, 'bananas']])` would work for your example.

More generally, `" ".join(str(x) for x in iterable)` works.